# Overlaying Pie Charts in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, charts, pie-chart

I am making a pie chart to go along with a series of plots all made in ggplot2. The data I'm using have two categories broken in to a total of three subcategories. Basically, the data look like this:

```
    Category Category_Value Super_Category
    <fctr>   <dbl>          <dbl>
 1  A        0.03733874     1
 2  B        0.66732754     0
 3  C        0.29533372     1
```

Here is the basic pie chart I have at the subcategory level:

[image: Pie]

And here is what I'd like to have (or something similar):

[image: Better Pie]

I had never made a pie chart in ggplot2 before, so here is my basic code to generate the top plot:

```
pie.chart <- ggplot(pie.data, aes(x = "", y = Category_Value, fill = Category, width = 1)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#4DAF4A", "#377EB8", "#E41A1C")) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.grid   = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks   = element_blank()
  )
```

Is this something that's doable? I messed around with making another plot grouped at the major category level and overlaying them without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `annotate` to get an approximation of your picture.

Firstly I've used your small subset of data

```
pie.data <- data.frame(
  Category = c("A", "B", "C"),
  Category_Value = c(0.03733874, 0.66732754, 0.29533372),
  Super_Category = c(1,0,1))
```

Then I've appplied your code

```
pie.chart <- ggplot(pie.data, aes(x = "", y = Category_Value, fill = Category, width = 1)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#4DAF4A", "#377EB8", "#E41A1C")) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.grid   = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks   = element_blank()
  )
```

And Finnaly I drew line using

```
pie.chart + annotate("rect", xmin = 1.5, xmax = 1.9, ymin = 0,2, ymax = 0.30, alpha=0,colour = "black")
```

And the output:

[image]

**Note** that because you have more data that my sample you will have to play with the settings values of `ymin = 0,2`, `ymax = 0.30` in `annotate` in order your line will cover values that you want.

Comment: Ah, since this is like a stacked bar, converting to polar maintains the shape. Great idea. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad to help.